# C - Pass a function a pointer to a pointer to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have a function header in a library that looks like this:

```
void deepCopy(CList ** clone, CList * cl, void * (* data_clone) (void * d));
```

I am having tremendous difficulty in passing it the deep_clone function properly.

This is what I am trying currently

```
CList *ys2 = &ys;
void (*dc) (void *) = &data_clone;
void (**dc2) (void *) = &dc;
deepCopy(&ys2, &xs, dc2);
```

The gcc output is:
testclist.c: In function ‘test_deep_copy’:
testclist.c:504: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘deepCopy’ from incompatible pointer type

I have tried cdecl.org on my declaration of dc2, and it says it is what I assume would be correct.

Any help is much appreciated; thank you.

Comment: If you already know cdecl, use it on data_clone :)

Comment: It says there are syntax errors. It doesn't seem to like function headers.

Comment: You need to leave out the argument name, like in `explain void * (* data_clone) (void *)`. You should also do that in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not expecting "a pointer to a pointer to a function", it's expecting simply a pointer to a function.

```
deepCopy(..., &data_clone);
```

should suffice.

Comment: Thank you. That makes it run, but it still insists on warning me about it. Am I able to stop that?

Comment: It is: testclist.c: In function ‘test_deep_copy’:
testclist.c:505: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘deepCopy’ from incompatible pointer type

Comment: @ratbum: And how is `data_clone` declared?

Comment: There is no prototype: void data_clone(void *d) {...}

Comment: @ratbum: Ok, that's not the same. The function needs to return `void *`, not `void`.

Comment: Oh OK, that explains a lot; thank you. I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Both `dc` and `dc2` return `void`. `deepCopy` expectes a function returning `void *`.

If `data_clone` is defined as `void * data_clone(void * d)` then just pass `&data_clone` directly.

Don't let the second star in `void * (* data_clone) (void * d));` confuse you, it's just syntactical sugar to tell the compiler you are talking about a pointer to a *function*. It's a "simple" pointer to a function returning `void *` and accepting `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the function like this:

```
deepCopy(..., data_clone);
```

The function should take a void* as argument and return a void*. That is the meaning of the first void* you see there.

You should not need an ampersand, *that would actually mean* a pointer to a pointer since it's already a pointer, data_clone alone is enough.

Example:

```
void *test_callback(void *p) {
    char *c = p;
    *c = 'z';
    return c;
}

void test_func(char *a, void* (*callback)(void *p)) {
    char *p = callback(a);
    printf("%c\n", *p);
}
```

And later on..

```
char c = 'a';
test_func(&c, test_callback);
```